# Published npm package does not apply styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm currently working on creating an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clear-carousel). Which is basically a React component with added styles using SCSS. When I test it out, the class names are there, but no styles are being applied.

Here is the repo for the [package](https://github.com/RobCC/react-clear-carousel#readme). I use a separated webpack config for building the specific folder where the component is.

Here's the webpack configuration I'm using:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const EsLintFormatter = require('eslint-formatter-pretty');
const path = require('path');

const pkg = require('../../package.json');
const { SRC_PATH, BUILD_PATH } = require('./constants');
const setStyleLoaders = require('./style-loaders');
const alias = require('./alias');

const packageName = pkg.name;

module.exports = ({ NODE_ENV }) => ({
  mode: 'production',
  entry: `${SRC_PATH}/components/Carousel/Carousel.js`,
  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: packageName,
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    publicPath: '/build/',
  },
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...alias,
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-dom'),
    },
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    reactDom: 'react-dom',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              formatter: EsLintFormatter,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: setStyleLoaders(NODE_ENV),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|pje?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'images',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|tff|otf|eot)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'fonts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'index.css' }),
  ],
});
```

...and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-clear-carousel",
  "version": "0.1.0-beta.1",
  "description": "A test",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --env.NODE_ENV=development --config config/webpack/webpack.config.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.NODE_ENV=production --config config/webpack/webpack.config.publish.js",
    "stylelint": "stylelint 'src/**/*.scss' --config stylelint.config.js; exit 0",
    "eslint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'; exit 0",
    "es:fix": "eslint 'src/**/*.js' --fix",
    "style:fix": "stylelint 'src/**/*.scss' --fix",
    "lint": "npm run eslint && npm run stylelint",
    "publish:beta": "npm publish --tag=beta",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/RobCC/web-playground.git"
  },
  "author": "robcc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/RobCC/web-playground/issues"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/config/jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^~/(.*)": "<rootDir>/$1",
      "^#/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/RobCC/web-playground#readme",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.1",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^4.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "chalk": "^3.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-formatter-pretty": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "log-symbols": "^3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "pr*op-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "stylelint": "^13.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-formatter-pretty": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.16.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "weak-key": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

This is the result when testing the published package:

[image: Classnames applied]

**Edit 1:**

There are no errors on the Network and Console tab in devtools. I also can't find the file loaded, even though it's there in the package. It seems like the js file is not using it, but it should.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for pointing me on the right direction!

I added `import 'react-clear-carousel/build/index.css';` to include the CSS file from my package. I can see the file now (on devtools), but the styles are not being applied since `css-loader` is modularizing it and adding additional suffix and prefix (even though it already had them), thus having different class names that the ones my component has.

*eg.* My component is rendered as `<div class="carousel_swimlane--kXSjh">`, but the styles in the DOM are named as `index_carousel_swimlane--kXSjh--2C`.

I guess the question is now, how do I tell Webpack to pass this CSS as is? And if there's a way for me to deliver the CSS file without other people having to change their Webpack configuration.

[image: Class names have double suffixes]

Comment: Troubleshooting: is your stylesheet successfully loaded? No 404's in the network tab? Also the next simplest test is to clear the browser cache.

Comment: No 404 errors in the Network tab. I also can't find the file loaded, even though it's there in the package. It seems like the js file is not using it, but it should

Comment: Sounds like the asset is either compiled empty or not loading. You need to verify the contents are there.

Comment: The CSS file is there. If I check its folder in node_modules, both CSS and JS files are there. And since the class names are being applied correctly, it mean that the CSS file is there. The codebase (where it has my package as a dependency) is just not applying these styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your repo I see that you are importing your scss but attributing it's properties to classNames.

`className` should be the name of the class, and you can either attribute your imported styles to `style` or you can load your compiled css into the DOM using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.min.css">`

The reason you're not seeing a stylesheet in the network tab is because you've simply forgotten to declare a stylesheet.

Comment: But considering that I want to share this component with its styles to others, how can I tell their codebase to include that CSS file and apply the styles my component need? The CSS file is already on the node_modules, it's just not being used

Comment: All packages need instructions for use, I believe, so I would say one of those instructions should be that HTML link element that they need to include in their HTML. Name it something unique so it doesn't compete with other stylesheets, instruct users to place the link after bootstrap but before custom stylesheets, for example, and use very specific css selectors and unique naming conventions so that users can overwrite styles as needed.

Comment: I tried to import the css files from the node_modules (import 'react-clear-carousel/build/index.css'). I can see the CSS file in the Sources tab on devtools, but still the styles are not applied.

Comment: Do you have that link element in the DOM? The browser has to be explicitly told that it is a stylesheet and it is for using in that document.

Comment: In the end the issue was with my Webpack configuration. I tried my package on a project using CRA, added the import to pull the CSS from the node_modules and that did it. At first I was under the misconception that the CSS should be pulled automatically since the JS was was using it. Thank you for the clarification and pointing me to the right direction. I'll mark your answer as accepted.